# Behavior difference between always_comb and always@(*)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I just found that always@(*) does not work as expected when it involve `function`.

Please see simple sample code below.

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/J7M

```
module test;
  reg a, b, c;

  function reg my_func();
    if (b==0) begin
      $display("DEBUG 0 @%0t", $time);
      return a;
    end
    else if (b==1) begin
      $display("DEBUG 1 @%0t", $time);
      return ~a;
    end
    else begin
      $display("DEBUG 2 @%0t", $time);
      return 0;
    end
  endfunction

  always @(*) begin
  //always_comb begin
    c = my_func();
  end

  initial begin
    a = 0; #10;
    a = 1; #10;
    a=0; 
  end
endmodule
```

Try to switch between `always @(*)` and `always_comb` in simulation. If I use `always @(*)`, nothing will display. But if I use `always_comb`, it will show expected result as follows:

```
DEBUG 2 @0
DEBUG 2 @0
DEBUG 2 @10
DEBUG 2 @20
```

The above code is just simple combinational logic. 
Why `always @(*)` and `always_comb` show different result? Is it just simulation issue? Further experiment I noticed that it may have something to do with usage of `function` inside the always block.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The always `@(*)` block is sensitive to change of the values all the variables, that is read by always block or we can say which are at the right side inside the always block.

In your example, there are no any variables used inside always block, so this always `@(*)` block will not work here.

As per SV LRM,

> always_comb is sensitive to changes within the contents of a function,
>   whereas always @* is only sensitive to changes to the arguments of a
>   function.

i.e., whenever the variables inside a function will change, the always_comb will trigger, but in your case, always @(*) will only trigger if we pass an argument in the function.

So either you can use,

```
  always @(*) begin
    c = my_func(b);  
  end
```

or you can use,

```
  always_comb begin
    c = my_func();  
  end
```

I have modified your code. Please find it in below link.

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/JiS

Answer (score 2):

`always @(*)` was added by Verilog IEEE 1364-2001 standard and replaced by `always_comb` in the SystemVerilog IEEE 1800-2005 standard. `always @(*)` should no longer be used because it does not correctly simulate hardware in all cases. In addition to the difference you note with functions, it does not handle constant logic correctly.

```
parameter C = 0;
reg A,B;
always @(*) A = B && C;
```

`A` remains unknown until there is a change on `B`. Whereas using always_comb will immediately set `A` to 0 because execution at time 0 is guaranteed.