# Can I combine always @* procedure blocks

Tags: system-verilog

I have a systemverilog module. This module have a lot of always @* blocks. I am just starting out with systemverilog and I am wondering that is there any particular reason that those blocks cannot be put together as just 1 always @* block?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no *technical* reasons that you could not put everything in one `always` block, just like there are no technical reasons you couldn't put most of your code on a single line. It is just a matter of readability and maintainability.

BTW, since you are using SystemVerilog, use `always_comb` which replaces `always @(*)` in Verilog. [Behavior difference between always_comb and always@(*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32778798/behavior-difference-between-always-comb-and-always)

Comment: Thank you for clarification and the link.